# Unknown column in database by eloquent query

Tags: mysql, laravel-5.1, between

I am creating a criteria for Señor high and tertiary.
Im trying to retrieve data that meets the condition but my query resulted to an error.

**Example:**

If this child is grade 12 and his final grade point average is 85 then this should be converted to college grading system(see conditions).

See the error below.Anyone knows why im getting this error and why saying unknown column even if i dont have such column?

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '1.5' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `scholar_cards` where `scholar_card_id` = 93 and `1`.`5` between 1.2 and 1.9)

```
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($card_id as $id) {

        $card = ScholarCard::find($id);
        if ($card->scholar_grade_level == 12) {
            if ($card->scholar_GPA == 100 || $card->scholar_GPA == 99 || $card->scholar_GPA == 98 || $card->scholar_GPA == 97 || $card->scholar_GPA == 96 || $card->scholar_GPA == 95 ) {
             $card_gpa = 1.0;
            }elseif ($card->scholar_GPA == 94) {
                $card_gpa = 1.1;
            }elseif ($card->scholar_GPA == 93) {
                $card_gpa = 1.2;
            }elseif ($card->scholar_GPA == 92) {
                $card_gpa = 1.3;
            }elseif ($card->scholar_GPA == 91) {
                $card_gpa = 1.4;
            }elseif ($card->scholar_GPA == 90) {
                $card_gpa = 1.5;
            }elseif ($card->scholar_GPA == 89) {
                $card_gpa = 1.6;
            }elseif ($card->scholar_GPA == 88) {
                $card_gpa = 1.7;
            }elseif ($card->scholar_GPA == 87) {
                $card_gpa = 1.8;
            }elseif ($card->scholar_GPA == 86) {
                $card_gpa = 1.9;
            }elseif ($card->scholar_GPA == 85) {
                $card_gpa = 2.0;
            }elseif ($card->scholar_GPA == 84) {
                $card_gpa = 2.1;
            }elseif ($card->scholar_GPA == 83) {
                $card_gpa = 2.2;
            }elseif ($card->scholar_GPA == 82) {
                $card_gpa = 2.3;
            }elseif ($card->scholar_GPA == 81) {
                $card_gpa = 2.4;
            }elseif ($card->scholar_GPA == 80) {
                $card_gpa = 2.5;
            }elseif ($card->scholar_GPA == 79) {
                $card_gpa = 2.6;
            }elseif ($card->scholar_GPA == 78) {
                $card_gpa = 2.7;
            }elseif ($card->scholar_GPA == 77) {
                $card_gpa = 2.8;
            }elseif ($card->scholar_GPA == 76) {
                $card_gpa = 2.9;
            }elseif ($card->scholar_GPA == 75) {
                $card_gpa = 3.0;
            }else {
                $card_gpa = 5.0;
            }
        }else{
            $card_gpa = $card->scholar_GPA;
        }
        $scholar_id2s = ScholarCard::where('scholar_card_id','=',$card->scholar_card_id)->whereBetween($card_gpa,[$scholarship->scholarship_gpa_to, $scholarship->scholarship_gpa_from])->get();

        $count++;         
    }
```

Comment: it's explains itself , the first argument in `whereBetween` must be the column name.

Comment: @Mr.Phoenix  - Ah that is why,but how can i do that in my current code just to get the right query?